# It it wasn't FOR or BECAUSE OF

Tags: grammar

> If it wasn't for the view, this would be a lovely room

and

> If it wasn't because of the view,...

Which one should I use? Are they different from each other

Comment: *for* = because. "**7.** As a result of; because of: *jumped for joy*."; *conj*. Because; since. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/for

Comment: However, here it's used more in the idiomatic sense of the *but for* Idiom: *but for* Were it not for: except for: *We would have reached the summit but for the weather.*

Comment: Here’s another example: ‘Oh! it really is a wery pretty garden / And Chingford to the Eastward could be seen / Wiv a ladder and some glasses / You could see to 'Ackney Marshes / If it wasn't for the 'ouses in between.’

Comment: Related: [When are “because”, “since”,“for” and “as” interchangeable?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6993/when-are-because-since-for-and-as-interchangeable)

Comment: @Reg I'm not too happy about the substitution of 'If it wasn't / (weren't) because of . . .' for 'If it wasn't / weren't for . . .' (ie with dummy rather than referential _it_). I don't think the linked article covers this.

Comment: Use *"for"*. You can use *"wasn't because"* in sentences like: *"Nobody ever returned to the Paradise Hotel. If it wasn't because of the insects, it was because of the food."*

Answer (score 2):

The correct choice is "for":

> If it wasn't for the view, this would be a lovely room.

It is also common to use "weren't":

> And I would have gotten away with it, too, if it weren't for you meddling kids!

The alternative of using "because of" is typically only used as such:

> Because of the view, this is a lovely room.
>
> I got away with it because of you meddling kids!

To phrase your original example this way, it would be:

> Because of the view, this isn't a lovely room.