# How to use for as a conjunction

Tags: conjunctions

When I recall the short way of remembering a list of the conjunctions, FANBOYS, for, and, nor, but, or, yet, so, how could for be used as a conjunction? Could it be used in

> Justin and Mark could not see, for they were blind.

Comment: Shouldn't it be _could **not** see_? _for_ means _because_.

Comment: What does this question have to do with choosing between _to_ and _for_? There's nothing about _to_ in the question.

Comment: @Barmar I fixed both of them now.

Comment: Anyway, the answer to your question is in the dictionary.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/598864/2085).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Justin and Mark could not see, for they were blind.

The sentence makes sense and is correct. There's a saying "can't see the forest for the trees" which also uses *for* in this way. However, this construction is formal sounding and maybe a little old fashioned. Most people would say:

> Justin and Mark could not see because they were blind.

Comment: So it's just of a matter of preference and the time period?

Comment: pretty much. it's not that it's archaic or anything; the construction makes sense in speech today, it's just a little formal.

Comment: @JoeyChor there's [a question for that](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6993/when-are-because-since-for-and-as-interchangeable).